# How to make subquery with filter in sqlalchemy

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, orm

```
 SELECT men.judul, 
  (SELECT 
       group_concat(m_trainer.nama_karyawan ORDER BY m_trainer.nama_karyawan) AS nama_trainer
    FROM m_detail_kelas_admin
         INNER JOIN m_kelas_admin
            ON     m_kelas_admin.id_kelas = m_detail_kelas_admin.id_kelas
               AND m_kelas_admin.status_aktif = 1
         INNER JOIN m_materi_admin
            ON     m_materi_admin.id_materi = m_detail_kelas_admin.id_materi
               AND m_materi_admin.status_aktif = 1
         INNER JOIN m_trainer
            ON     FIND_IN_SET(m_trainer.nik, m_materi_admin.trainer) > 0
    WHERE men.id_kelas = m_kelas_admin.id_kelas) AS list_guru
FROM m_kelas_admin men;
```

I'm using sqlalchemy and Im trying to execute the above query.
How syntax is equal in sqlalchemy ?

I tried this

```
detail_kelas = model_kelas_admin.m_detail_kelas_admin
  kelas = model_kelas_admin.m_kelas_admin
  materi = model_materi_admin.m_materi_admin
  trainer = model_activity.m_trainer
  subquery_trainer = db.session.query(detail_kelas).\
    join(kelas, and_(kelas.id_kelas == detail_kelas.id_kelas, kelas.status_aktif == 1)).\
    join(materi, and_(materi.id_materi == detail_kelas.id_materi, materi.status_aktif == 1)).\
    join(trainer, and_(func.find_in_set(trainer.nik, materi.trainer), trainer.status_aktif == 1)).\
    filter(
      detail_kelas.status_aktif == "1",
      detail_kelas.id_kelas == kelas.id_kelas --reference this
    ).with_entities(
      func.group_concat(trainer.nama_karyawan).label('nama_trainer')
    ).scalar_subquery()
  # subquery_jsa = db.session.query(func.group_concat(jsa.langkah_kerja.distinct()).label('list_trainer') ).filter(and_(jsa.request_id == request.request_id, jsa.status_aktif == 1)).order_by(jsa.request_id).limit(1).scalar_subquery()
  data = db.session.query(kelas).\
    filter(
      kelas.status_aktif == "1"
    ).with_entities(
      kelas.id_kelas,
      kelas.judul,
      subquery_trainer.label('list_trainer')
    ).all()
```

but the result is different.
How can I reference kelas.id_kelas in 'detail_kelas' from 'data' kelas.id_kelas ?

Answer (score 0):

I tried so many ways and drink coffe to get the answer.

```
detail_kelas = model_kelas_admin.m_detail_kelas_admin
  kelas = model_kelas_admin.m_kelas_admin
  materi = model_materi_admin.m_materi_admin
  trainer = model_activity.m_trainer
  
  data = db.session.query(kelas).\
    filter(
      kelas.status_aktif == "1"
    ).with_entities(
      kelas.id_kelas,
      kelas.judul,
      db.session.query(detail_kelas).\
        join(materi, and_(materi.id_materi == detail_kelas.id_materi, materi.status_aktif == 1)).\
        join(trainer, and_(func.find_in_set(trainer.nik, materi.trainer), trainer.status_aktif == 1)).\
        filter(
          detail_kelas.status_aktif == "1",
          detail_kelas.id_kelas == kelas.id_kelas
        ).with_entities(
          func.group_concat(trainer.nama_karyawan).label('nama_trainer')
        ).scalar_subquery().label('list_trainer')
      # subquery_trainer.label('list_trainer')
      # Total materi iki mengko di count dari materi per kelas wae
      # Nama trainer di string agg dari materi per kelas
      # 
    ).all()
```

I dont separate subquery and main query. So, I can call reference kelas.id_kelas.